# Transform data from one shape to another in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How would I go about transforming this shape of data below using Javascript (es6 is fine).

From:

```
[
  {
    name: "Color",
    options: [{ value: "Gold" }, { value: "Space grey" }]
  },
  {
   name: "Size",
     options: [{ value: 32 }, { value: 64 }]
  },
  {
    name: "Width",
    options: [{ value: 100 }, { value: 200 }]
  }
]
```

To:

```
[
  {
    properties: {
      Color: "Gold",
      Size: 32,
      Width: 100
    }
  },
  {
    properties: {
      Color: "Gold",
      Size: 32,
      Width: 200
    }
  },
  {
    properties: {
      Color: "Gold",
      Size: 64,
      Width: 100
    }
  },
  {
    properties: {
      Color: "Gold",
      Size: 64,
      Width: 200
    }
  },
  {
    properties: {
      Color: "Space grey",
      Size: 32,
      Width: 100
    }
  },
  {
    properties: {
      Color: "Space grey",
      Size: 32,
      Width: 200
    }
  },
  {
    properties: {
      Color: "Space grey",
      Size: 64,
      Width: 100
    }
  },
  {
    properties: {
      Color: "Space grey",
      Size: 64,
      Width: 200
    }
  }
]
```

The second shape is every possible combination of options of the first shape.

I'm trying to build a product form that can handle products that have variants e.g. Color, Size, Material etc. Each of those variants can have multiple options. e.g. For Color, they could be Red, Blue, Orange etc. To get this to work I think I need to get a list that generates all possible combinations so that I can attach a price to each.

Would appreciate any help as I'm stumped :(

Below is what I tried. But its the wrong shape.

```js
let variants = [{
    name: "Color",
    options: [{
      value: "Gold"
    }, {
      value: "Space grey"
    }]
  },
  {
    name: "Size",
    options: [{
      value: "32"
    }, {
      value: "64"
    }]
  },
  {
    name: "Width",
    options: [{
      value: "100"
    }, {
      value: "200"
    }]
  }
]

const [primaryOption, ...otherOptions] = variants

let options = []
primaryOption.options.map(x => {
  otherOptions.map(y => {
    y.options.map(z => {
      options = [
        ...options,
        {
          properties: {
            [primaryOption.name]: x.value,
            [y.name]: z.value
          }
        }
      ]
    })
  })
})

console.log(options)
```

Comment: I believe that this question does not suite for newbie at all.

Comment: @Archer, I've tried various forms of reduce and map. But none of them came close.

Comment: Three nested loops would get you there.

Comment: @Archer, Fair enough. I've added my attempt. Didn't think it was worth mentioning it as its seems far off a solution. I'll try using loops as Robby Cornelissen suggested.

Comment: Nah, that shows that you've at least researched the problem and attempted something yourself which most people on here want to see.  It's a better quality question and usually gets a better quality of answer, which is what Stack Overflow is all about.  Thanks for updating :)

Comment: "To get this to work I think I need to get a list that generates all possible combinations so that I can attach a price to each."

It depends how you want to do your pricing, but there's no reason why this should be necessary. You could simply have a base price (e.g. `$20`) and a modifier for each option (e.g. `+$3` for large sizes). Your data might look like this: `{
   name: "Size",
     options: [{value: 32, modifier: 0}, {value: 64, , modifier: 3}]
  },`
etc.

Comment: @LionelRowe Sorry, but havinga  base price and a modifier for each item is a terrible idea.  If you change the base price then every item will potentially be wrong, or you could change an item modifier and that specific item will be wrong.  Every item has a price - that's a 1-to-1 relationship and *a lot* easier to maintain than what you suggest.

Comment: @LionelRowe I started with that idea. But I looked at how Facebook (Businesses Pages > Products), Shopify and Squarespace did it, and they all took the simpler approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 let result = [{}];

 for(const {name, options} of input) {
   const previous = result;
   result = [];
   for(const {value} of options) {
      for(const prev of previous)
         result.push({ ...prev, [name]: value });
   }
}
```

Just use a nested loop to go over all values, and build up a new array with them.

Comment: This works perfectly thank you. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @notexactly glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let variants = [{
    name: "Color",
    options: [{
      value: "Gold"
    }, {
      value: "Space grey"
    }]
  },
  {
    name: "Size",
    options: [{
      value: 32
    }, {
      value: 64
    }]
  },
  {
    name: "Width",
    options: [{
      value: 100
    }, {
      value: 200
    }]
  }
];

let endIndex = variants[0].options.length;
let result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < endIndex; i++) {
  variants.forEach(x => {
    result[i] = result[i] || {properties:{}};
    result[i].properties[x.name] = x.options[i].value;
  });
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take the cartesian product by iterating the outer array and take the inner array for the values to append objects.

```js
function getCartesian(array) {
    return array.reduce((r, { name, options }) => {
        var temp = [];
        r.forEach(({ property }) =>
            options.forEach(({ value }) => temp.push({ property: Object.assign({}, property, { [name]: value }) }))
        );
        return temp;
    }, [{}]);
}

var data = [{ name: "Color", options: [{ value: "Gold" }, { value: "Space grey" }] }, { name: "Size", options: [{ value: 32 }, { value: 64 }] }, { name: "Width", options: [{ value: 100 }, { value: 200 }] }];

console.log(getCartesian(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```